# Qt desinger generate empty ui file

Tags: linux, qt, qt-designer

Im working with Qt Designer, when i save my work, it generate an empty .ui file (0 Bytes)

```
pyuic5 test29.ui -o test29.pi
```

returns

> Error in input file: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: Not sure how we possibly can help on this. In the 10 years I have used qt-designer it has never done this. Perhaps you are looking in the wrong folder. Did you verify the path / see that the file update time was correct? Also what version of `Qt` are you using and what os?

Comment: Qt4 Designer in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @SlimaneMEHARZI share your .ui.

Comment: @eyllanesc, as i mentionned, Qt designer generates me an empty fil, so my .ui is empty

Comment: I think if you can show that this happens you need to create a bug report at `ubuntu` for your version of `Qt`.

Comment: @SlimaneMEHARZI 
Then reinstall Qt Designer, that problem is support and not programming.

Comment: @eyllanesc, Thank so much, i'll do